# how to convert arabic ascii text to hex?

Tags: c, hex

The code in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519793), works with latin chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void charToHex(char *a)
{
    char word[17], outword[33];//17:16+1, 33:16*2+1
    int i, len;

    strcpy(word, a);
    len = strlen(word);
    if(word[len-1]=='\n')
        word[--len] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
        sprintf(outword+i*2, "%02X", word[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", outword);
}

int main(void) 
{
    char ch[10]="a";
    charToHex(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

It writes 61 for "a". But if I put "[ق](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qoph#Arabic_q.C4.81f)" in ch[10], it returns FFFFFFFF82. But it should be D982.
How can I get true Hex value for Arabic letters?
You can try code with [ideone](http://ideone.com/YTGpKF).

Thanks.

Comment: `sprintf(outword+i*2, "%02X", (unsigned char)word[i])`

Comment: "ق" is not a member of the ASCII character set. If you say the encoding should be D982 then you are using the Unicode character set with the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D9 = 1101 1001. which becomes a -ve 1 byte number . try using unsigned array it will work