# Convert array of hex values to corresponding ascii characters

Tags: c

I want to convert an array of hexadecimal numbers to their corresponding ascii character?

For eg:

```
arr_hex[] = {6,1,6,2,6,5,6,A,7,A}
```

to

```
arr_ascii[] = {a,b,e,j,z}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16519056/3933332

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean `0xA` rather than `A`. Anyway, a shift + add should do the trick.

Comment: That's a bad aproach.Why didn't you use something like `int arr_hex[] = {0x61,0x62,0x65,0x6A,0x7A}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 10
#define B 11
#define C 12
#define D 13
#define E 14
#define F 15

int main(void){
    int arr_hex[] = {6,1,6,2,6,5,6,A,7,A};
    int size = sizeof(arr_hex)/sizeof(*arr_hex);
    char arr_ascii[size/2];
    int i, j;
    for(j=i=0; j < size/2; i+=2){
        printf("%c", arr_ascii[j++] = arr_hex[i]*16 + arr_hex[i+1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```