# Convert to ascii to hex without using print

Tags: c, hex

So I want to be able to somehow change a string into hex like so: "ab.c2" --> "61622e6332". All the help I've found online shows how to do it by using print, but I don't want to use print because it doesn't store the hex value.

What I know so far is that if you take a char and cast it to an int you get the ascii value and with that I can get the hex, which is where I'm stumped.

Comment: What is `print`? There's nothing by that name in C. Do you mean `printf`?

Comment: You don't need to cast a char to an int. `char` is an integer type in C.

Comment: You can iterate  through the string character by character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ascii char\[\] to hexadecimal char\[\] in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519056/convert-ascii-char-to-hexadecimal-char-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's *one* way to do it, a complete program but the "meat" is in the `tohex` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * tohex (unsigned char *s) {
    size_t i, len = strlen (s) * 2;

    // Allocate buffer for hex string result.
    // Only output if allocation worked.

    char *buff = malloc (len + 1);
    if (buff != NULL) {
        // Each char converted to hex digit string
        // and put in correct place.

        for (i = 0; i < len ; i += 2) {
            sprintf (&(buff[i]), "%02x", *s++);
        }
    }

    // Return allocated string (or NULL on failure).

    return buff;
}

int main (void) {
    char *input = "ab.c2";

    char *hexbit = tohex (input);
    printf ("[%s] -> [%s]\n", input, hexbit);
    free (hexbit);

    return 0;
}
```

There are of course *other* ways to achieve the same result, such as avoiding memory allocation if you can ensure you provide your own buffer that's big enough, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tohex (unsigned char *in, char *out) {
    while (*in != '\0') {
        sprintf (out, "%02x", *in++);
        out += 2;
    }
}

int main (void) {
    char input[] = "ab.c2";
    char output[sizeof(input) * 2 - 1];
    tohex (input, output);
    printf ("[%s] -> [%s]\n", input, output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if what s/he really wants is `uint64_t result=0x61622e6332`. The question is not at all clear on that point.

Comment: @user3386109, that may be so but the fact they stated `"ab.c2" --> "61622e6332"` seems to indicate a _string_ result. Additionally, they state "without using print" (printf presumably) and there's no sane way to get an integral value from a string with `printf` :-)

Comment: And the green check confirms that :)