# c: sending string character by character as hex representation

Tags: c, arrays, hex

```
char str[] = "05AD2101";
```

I have a function sendChar and I want to send this str chars in a pair of two as hex values as follows:

```
sendChar(0x05);

sendChar(0xAD);

sendChar(0x21);

sendChar(0x01);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: you mean with a loop over str, and send each to sendChar()

Comment: yes.. but how to convert str into individual hex

Comment: For that see this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519056/convert-ascii-char-to-hexadecimal-char-in-c

Comment: Do not use smart quotes,  Use `"45AD2101"` and a code editor.

Comment: Oh, so many ways.  This seems pretty broad.

Comment: Are you certain you want to send `sendChar(0x04), sendChar(0x05) ...` instead of `sendChar('4'), sendChar('5') ...`?  Seems unusual to want the former.

Comment: thanku for the replies.. I have modified the q.. can u please have a look at it aswell

Comment: This question seems to be fundamentally about how to convert your hex string into a byte array. From there, you just need to send() each byte.

Answer (score 2):

I did not tested this, there could be syntax errors:

```
int char2hex(char c){
   switch(c){
       case '0' : return 0x00;
       case '1' : return 0x01;
       case '2' : return 0x02;
       // until 9
       case 'A' : return 0x0a;
       case 'B' : return 0x0b;
       case 'C' : return 0x0c;
       // until F
   }
   return -1; // unknown char
}

void send(char str[]){
    if (!str)
        return;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
        sendChar(char2hex(str[i]));
}
```

If you need more help, pls comment.

Update:

There could be many improvements, checking for NULL, put `const` around, checking for lowercase A,B,C,D,E,F etc.

You could even do something like - but test it prior use it:

```
int char2hex(char c){
   if (c < 'A')
      return c - '0';
   else
      return c - 'A' + 10;
}
```

Comment: Check the argument of `send` .

Comment: Note: simpler to do `for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i)`

Comment: but for A char i want 0x0A.. and for B 0x0B and so on

Comment: 10 is same as 0x0A. If you want to show your *intention*, no problem to use hexadecimals in the switch, e.g. `case '1': return 0x01;`. Also note what will happen if switch not match, for example if there is 'R'.

Comment: @chux - right, I'll edit.

Comment: @chux - correct, pls edit the answer, just keep it simple for user3061597