# In C, how to print char[] as escaped hex?

Tags: c, string, char, hex

So say I have:

```
char [] = "cat"
```

I want to print it in escaped hex so it looks like:

```
"\x63\x61\x74"
```

Is there a way to do this without parsing/constructing a new `char[]` with the escaped hex?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519793/4520911) here...On another note: _"Is there a way to do this without parsing/constructing a new `char[]` with the escaped hex?"_ Hmm...parse basically means to break something down into smaller pieces/analyze it.  How do you expect to print something out like this without "parsing" each specific character?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build a new `char[]`, a loop with `printf` will do:

```
char c[] = "cat";
size_t len = strlen(c);
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
    printf("\\x%02x", (unsigned char)c[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/oxETk0)

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers, would be to check for `\0`. After all, it is a C-string.

Comment: @M.M Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `x` in your `printf` format string:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\\x%02x", (unsigned char)str[i]);
}
```